# Word insertOoxml method returning Error: Unknown for all input

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have an existing Word Add-In solution that has been working well for a long time that now cannot insert OOXML content into Word documents. Trying to break this down I can't get the insertOoxml method to work under any circumstance.

To reproduce:

```
        await Word.run(async (context) => {
            context.document.getSelection().insertOoxml(theOoxml, 'Start');
            await context.sync();
        });
```

Where theOoxml can be any valid Ooxml string.  The reference example I have been using is:

```
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml" />
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid wp14">
        <w:body>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>
                    Hey there
                </w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
</pkg:package>
```

But have also tried other reference examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml

Results in:

> word-web-16.00.debug.js:11162 Uncaught (in promise) Error: unknown
>       at new RuntimeError (word-web-16.00.debug.js:11162)
>       at RequestContext.ClientRequestContext.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (word-web-16.00.debug.js:13713)
>       at word-web-16.00.debug.js:13620

Have tried it in different tenants, browsers, and this is driving me a bit bonkers.  If this does work for you please let me know your general config/setup.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

To avoid questions about the validity of the XML itself, the following code gets the OOXML for the current selection and then duplicates it after the selection - also fails with the same error.

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {

   var sourceRange = context.document.getSelection();
   var contentToCopy = sourceRange.getOoxml();
   await context.sync();

   sourceRange.insertOoxml(contentToCopy.value, 'After');
   await context.sync();
});
```

Hopefully there is something simple I am missing here.  Any suggestions/workarounds for inserting **any** Ooxml fragment appreciated.

**UPDATE 2018-09-04:**
Microsoft have acknowledged the issue and are going to fix it.

**UPDATE 2018-09-12:**
InsertOoxml appears to be working again - although I have not had a confirmation from Microsoft regarding the fix.

Comment: I tried your xml on word desktop, it also can't insert anything. So I suspect the xml is invalid. So can you first try to call range.getOoxml() and take a look at the valid ooxml and then use that ooxml to call range.insertOoxml() API?

Comment: This is invalide Word Open XML: `<w:p>Hey there</w:p>` It's missing the `<w:r><w:t>` elements around the text that should appear. Type the text in a Word document then view the XML in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool and you'll see what I mean...

Comment: Encountering the same issue trying to replace body OoXML on the page, even with basic examples.

e.g. setting the body OoXML back to itself throws the same error even though the OoXML is the value given from querying `context.document.body.getOoXml()` and setting the `value` back on `insertOoXml(value)`

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks - I have updated the example XML with your suggested edits, and retried it but still fails with the same error.  I also added an example that just extracts the current selection as Ooxml and attempts to reinsert it.  Also fails with the same error.

Comment: @Hitmands thanks for confirming, I thought I was losing my mind.  I will investigate the possibility of opening a Microsoft support case for this - but i'm not hopeful.

Comment: Here's another confirmation that there's apparently a problem (likely introduced by an update): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52097263/inserting-ooxml-into-word-throwing-error-unknown

Comment: @JamesBoman thanks for updating the snippet I put in my ticket - I flagged this also. Trying to spike out validity of replacing Field Codes via OOXML and just getting failures at every turn.

Comment: @Peak My support case with Microsoft has been escalated - they acknowledged the issue and are going to fix it.

Comment: @JamesBoman Thanks for the update with Microsoft's response to the error. By chance, did they mention an estimate of when the bug will be fixed?

Comment: @CodeIntern worryingly no news on an ETA as yet.

Comment: hello all. The update is that we are actively working on a Sev1 escalation to fix this. we will let you know when done.  thanks and sorry about this inconvenience.

Comment: @JuanBalmori This now appears to be fixed for our customers - can you confirm the fix?

Answer (score 0):

InsertOoxml appears to be working again now as it was before.

I have not yet had a conformation from the Microsoft support case regarding the fix, but all my customers appears to be functioning again.

Thanks to [Juan Balmori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5904541/juan-balmori) and those working on the extensibility team for getting this fixed up.

J.