# Inserting OoXml into word throwing Error: Unknown

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I've been attempting to insert OOXML into the body content of word documents via the office-js `insertOoXML()` method. I've even tried the simplest of implementations (thinking I was doing something incorrect when attempting to replace fieldCodes in the XML itself) and all result in this `Error: unknown` response after saying its "inserting":

> Error: unknown
>       at new r (word-web-16.00.js:21)
>       at i.c.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (word-web-16.00.js:21)
>       at word-web-16.00.js:21

To reproduce - here's a simple example of getting the body OoXML and attempting to replace it back in:

```js
Word.run(async context => {
  const OOXML = context.document.body.getOoxml();
  await context.sync();
  context.document.body.insertOoxml(OOXML.value, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
  await context.sync().catch(console.error);
});
```

With the example above there is no chance that the OoXML is malformed as it's the direct result that office-js has returned to the client.

Any help with this would be much appreciated as manipulating Field Codes (as there's no native support) is a must for my Add-In.

Comment: Can you please clarify in what platform you are experiencing his?i am assuming Word Online ? What about in windows ? Also it’s important to understand what content is in the document.

Comment: @JuanBalmori Sure thing. I'm using Word 2016 on Mac, and Word online on Chrome, also on Safari (Mac Sierra). Same issue across the board.
The content of the document is a blank document with one paragraph which says 'Hello World'. Unfortunately I don't have a windows machine to test on - will need to test my on my VM.

Comment: @JuanBalmori Mistake - Word 2016 on Mac is fine (sorry - it's awkward to debug on sierra). It's the online versions which break.

Comment: @JuanBalmori This was also reported a day or so ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092107/word-insertooxml-method-returning-error-unknown-for-all-input

Comment: We are encountering this same problem, a few days ago this still worked. Haven't found a solution...

Comment: this is an active escalation in the team right now, we are working on a fix. our understanding is that Online is the only impacted platform.

Answer (score 3):

InsertOoxml is now working as it should for me.

Microsoft appears to have fixed this problem (Although I have not yet had official confirmation via my support case)

Thanks to [Juan Balmori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5904541/juan-balmori) and those working on the extensibility team for getting this fixed up.

J.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this!